# Get the last booking by its status (mysql)

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I currently have a table that contains reservations. Another table with different status assigned to a reservation. A reservation with several status to keep track of the different status.

I would like to retrieve all the bookings in relation to the LAST status of the reservation.

```
|             |            |                |                       | 
|-------------|------------|----------------|-----------------------| 
| Booking     |            |                |                       | 
| id          | name       |                |                       | 
| 1           | aaa        |                |                       | 
| 2           | bbb        |                |                       | 
| 3           | ccc        |                |                       | 
|             |            |                |                       | 
| Status      |            |                |                       | 
| id          | booking_id | type_status_id | date_of_change_status | 
| 1           | 1          | 1              | xxx-xx-xx 00:00:00    | 
| 2           | 1          | 2              | xxx-xx-xx 00:00:00    | 
| 3           | 2          | 1              | xxx-xx-xx 00:00:00    | 
| 4           | 2          | 2              | xxx-xx-xx 00:00:00    | 
|             |            |                |                       | 
| Type_status |            |                |                       | 
| id          | name       |                |                       | 
| 1           | Started    |                |                       | 
| 2           | Updated    |                |                       | 
| 3           | Finished   |                |                       |
```

Here is the code that I have for the moment, it returns well to me the reservations which passed by the status but not like last status.

```
SELECT b.name, b.id, b.date_booking, b.price, b.reference FROM booking b
        INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(s.id), s.booking_id, s.type_status_id FROM status s
                    WHERE s.type_status_id = 5
                    GROUP BY booking_id) AS status_max
        ON b.id = status_max.booking_id
```

Thanks

Comment: Where's the table structure?  Where the sample input?  Where's the sample output?  Here's the link how to create MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Excuse me, POST update

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Comment: It returns to me all the reservations which had the status "done" (for example -> type_status_id = 5)
And I would like the code to return all bookings that have the status "finished" last as the last status without taking into account the old status assigned to the reservation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the "latest" date of status change in a subquery using MAX() then include that as a subquery in the joins to restrict which rows from the status table get returned.

```
select
*
from Booking b
inner join Status s on b.id = s.bookingid
inner join (
   select booking_id, max(date_of_change_status) latest_status_date
   from status
   group by 
   ) l on b.id = l.bookingid
       and s.date_of_change_status = l.latest_status_date
inner join Type_status ts on s.type_status_id  = ts.id
```